Missing Android SDK tab within the SDK Manager of Android Studio
I'm trying to set up my Android Studio environment (Windows) for development for the first time. Following the official guide on developer.android.com .
The instructions say to open the Tools --> SDK Manager. Then Appearance & Behavior --> System Settings --> Android SDK --> SDK Tools --> Google USB Drive.
SDK Manager: Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings
However under system settings, I do not have a Android SDK tab. All forums online seem to already have it initially, or are missing the entire SDK manager.
What could the issue be?
I've checked:

File --> Project Structure --> SDK Location is set to the correct directory
Project Structure: SDK Location

Checked that the folder was populated.
Windows File Explorer, Sdk directory

All installed plugins in Android Studio are enabled

Reinstalled once


Possible Issue:
I installed all related files (as far as I can tell) on my D:\ drive do to space limitations on my C:\ (the default and containing my OS).
The folder structure is:
 D:\Android\...
      ...\Android Studio
      ...\AndroidStudioProjects
      ...\Sdk

I understand I can download the necessary drivers manually, but if possible I'd like to avoid that as a permanent solution.

I think that what you are looking for is under a different tab.

In that case, use the settings icon in the top right of Android Studio, and press SDK Manager.
It will open Settings -> Languages & Framework -> Android SDK

That was it, thanks. I don't know why I spent a couple hours trying to trouble shoot, and for some reason absolutely ignored that it could've been moved in an update. Appreciate you pointing it out
